# My redefinition of Haskell 'length' function won't work

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, type-mismatch, algebraic-data-types

Can someone please explain how I can fix my program.
Very new to Haskell, been trying to create a `length` function that calculates the length of a list of any type.

I am aiming to do this using `data` as I want to create a brand new type to do so (this is the area of Haskell that I'm currently learning, which is why it might not be the most efficient implementation of this function)

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)


len :: List a -> Int
len Nil         = 0
len (Cons _ xs) = 1 + len xs
```

If I run it on `len [1,2,3]`
I get the error:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘List a0’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • In the first argument of ‘len’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3]’
      In the expression: len [1, 2, 3]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = len [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is not a `List`.

Answer (score 11):

The function definition is correct, but `[1,2,3]` is not a `List a` object, it is a `[a]` (or more canonical `[] a`). A list like `[1,2,3]` as `List Int` is:

```
len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)))
```

Alternatively, you can make `List a` an instance of the `IsList` type class, and then use the `-XOverloadedLists` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts(IsList(Item, fromList, toList))

instance IsList (List a) where
    type Item (List a) = a
    fromList = foldr Cons Nil
    toList Nil = []
    toList (Cons x xs) = x : toList xs
```

Then we can use the `OverloadedLists` extension:

```
$ ghci -XOverloadedLists -XTypeFamilies
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/kommusoft/.ghci
Prelude> data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
Prelude> import GHC.Exts(IsList(Item, fromList, toList))
Prelude GHC.Exts> :{
Prelude GHC.Exts| instance IsList (List a) where
Prelude GHC.Exts|     type Item (List a) = a
Prelude GHC.Exts|     fromList = foldr Cons Nil
Prelude GHC.Exts|     toList Nil = []
Prelude GHC.Exts|     toList (Cons x xs) = x : toList xs
Prelude GHC.Exts| :}
Prelude GHC.Exts> :{
Prelude GHC.Exts| len :: List a -> Int
Prelude GHC.Exts| len Nil         = 0
Prelude GHC.Exts| len (Cons _ xs) = 1 + len xs
Prelude GHC.Exts| :}
Prelude GHC.Exts> len [1,2,3]
3
```

Comment: yep, makes sense. Thanks for the help